# Search value in an array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In the following scenario, how can I search both `label` and `value`?

```
var countries = [
    { label: 'United Kingdom', value: '44', group: "Europe" },
    { label: 'United States', value: '1', group: "North America" },
    { label: 'Norway', value: '47', group: "Europe" },
    { label: 'Sweden', value: '46', group: "Europe" },
    { label: 'Germany', value: '49', group: "Europe" }
];

text = 'uni';// Works fine since 'uni' is present in label
text = '44' // Should lookup value as well and return 'United Kingdom'

var suggestions = countries.filter(n => n.label.toLowerCase().includes(text));

console.log(suggestions);
```

[Link to JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/fitevukeda/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: `n => n.label.toLowerCase().includes(text) || n.value == text`?

Comment: Change line to - ```var suggestions = countries.filter(n => (n.label.toLowerCase().includes(text) + n.value.toLowerCase().includes(text))); ```

Answer (score 2):

just put or statement to filter

```
var suggestions = countries.filter(n => n.label.toLowerCase().includes(text) || n.value.toLowerCase().includes(text));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go for the and(&&) operator, I would also suggest making the 'suggestions' as a method which takes two parameters and fetches the correct item.

```
num = '46';
text = 'Sweden';
var suggestions = countries.filter(n => RegExp(text,'i').test(n.label) && n.value == num);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var countries = [
    { label: 'United Kingdom', value: '44', group: "Europe" },
    { label: 'United States', value: '1', group: "North America" },
    { label: 'Norway', value: '47', group: "Europe" },
    { label: 'Sweden', value: '46', group: "Europe" },
    { label: 'Germany', value: '49', group: "Europe" }
];

text = '44';

var suggestions = countries.filter(n => {  
  if(n.label.toLowerCase().includes(text)) {
    return true;
  }

  if (n.value.includes(text)) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
});

console.log(suggestions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `OR` condition, Following code will work for `label,value,group`

```js
var countries = [
    { label: 'United Kingdom', value: '44', group: "Europe" },
    { label: 'United States', value: '1', group: "North America" },
    { label: 'Norway', value: '47', group: "Europe" },
    { label: 'Sweden', value: '46', group: "Europe" },
    { label: 'Germany', value: '49', group: "Europe" }
];

text = 'europe';// Works
text = 'uni' // works
text = 44 // works

var suggestions = countries.filter(n => {

  return ( 
        n.label.toLowerCase().includes(text) ||
        n.group.toLowerCase().includes(text) ||
        n.value.includes(text)
     )

});

console.log(suggestions);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text = '44';
label = 'United Kingdom'

const suggestions = countries.filter(n => n.label.toLowerCase() === label.toLowerCase() && n.value === text);
```

I think what i understand, is that you just need to set `&&` or `||` statement and set condition for the label too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values` and `some` and `includes`

```js
var countries = [{ label: 'United Kingdom', value: '44', group: "Europe" },{ label: 'United States', value: '1', group: "North America" },{ label: 'Norway', value: '47', group: "Europe" },{ label: 'Sweden', value: '46', group: "Europe" },{ label: 'Germany', value: '49', group: "Europe" }];

const suggestions = searchTerm => countries.filter(n => Object.values(n).some(value => value.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)));

console.log(suggestions("uni"));
console.log(suggestions("44"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a `fuzzy search` using all the values. Convert all value as word and then match.

Useful methods: `Object.values`, `filter`

```js
const fuzzySearch = (countries, txt) => {
  return countries.filter((country) => {
    const word = Object.values(country).join("");
    return word.toLowerCase().includes(txt);
  });
};

const countries = [
  { label: "United Kingdom", value: "44", group: "Europe" },
  { label: "United States", value: "1", group: "North America" },
  { label: "Norway", value: "47", group: "Europe" },
  { label: "Sweden", value: "46", group: "Europe" },
  { label: "Germany", value: "49", group: "Europe" },
];
const suggestions = (keyword) => fuzzySearch(countries, keyword);
console.log(suggestions("uni"));
console.log(suggestions("44"));
```